# Launching an arbitrary executable over a file on Netbeans

Tags: command-line, netbeans, plugins

We want to add command-line support to Netbeans, as in being able to run any program (using the full path of the current file as the argument) directly from the IDE. The same way you can do it already on Notepad++ with the Run tool.

Apparently there is a plugin called VCS Generic Command-Line Support that offers this functionality, but when we try to install it we get this error message:

> **Some plugins require Master Filesystem to be installed**
>
> The plugin Master Filesystem is
>   requested in version >= 1.1 but only
>   2.15.2 was found.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

I Did some googling as you got me interested pretty much everything i found was in refernce to NetBeans 5.x or below... Im thinking maybe its not compatible with 6 - but thats just a guess.

---

Looks like a version incompatability with "Master Filesystem". Maybe they are checking the version improperly or perhaps they really mean it needs to be 1.x >= 1.1. Do you have the newest version of VCS Plugin?

As an aside if Im going to have to chek this out... ive been dying for external tool support like in my beloved Eclipse :-)

Comment: We get the same error when we try to install any plugin part of VCS Generics. I also thought it was a problem with the way the version number is checked. So far it seems that if we want this feature, we need to write a plugin for it.